# Remove Duplicate title in database table mysql

Tags: mysql, database, sql-delete, records

We have 2 tables called : "post" and "post_extra".

Summary construction of "post" table's are:
id, postdate, title, description.

And for post_extra they are:
eid, news_id, rating, views

"id" filed in the first table is connected to "news_id" to the second table.

There are more than 100,000 records on the table, that many of them are duplicated. I want to keep only one record and remove duplicate records on "post" table that have the same title, and then remove the connected record on "post_extra"

I ran this query on phpmyadmin but the server was crashed, and I had to restart it.

```
DELETE e FROM Post p1, Post p2, Post_extra e WHERE p1.postdate > p2.postdate AND p1.title = p2.title AND e.news_id = p1.id
```

How can I do this?

Comment: i havnt dont anything yet , i think i must be use SELECT DISTINCT but how?

Comment: do you want to delete by hightest postdate. like 2013 is hightest in your example....

Answer (score 1):

i think the the `id` is maximum in the case of highest `posteddate` if so you can try this code

```
DELETE from post where id in (select max(id) from post group by title)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE p1 
FROM Post p1, Post p2 
WHERE p1.postdate > p2.postdate AND p1.title = p2.title
```

Comment: Why not backup your tables and find out?

Comment: it will work if there is no tupple with same title and same year more than once.

Comment: there is table with name post_extra relation with post table how can i delete record that post id= post_extra id with your method ?

Comment: @user426069 DELETE e 
FROM Post p1, Post p2, Post_extra e
WHERE p1.postdate > p2.postdate AND p1.title = p2.title AND e.id = p1.id

Comment: i ran above code and mysql showing "Showing rows 0 - 0 ( 1 total, Query took 0.0004 sec)" message but nothing happen and nothing records was deleted

Comment: sorry showing this message : Your SQL query has been executed successfully ( Query took 0.4552 sec )